# JAXBContext y Unmarshaller usando XML en Java

Tags: java, xml, webservice

estoy trabajando con Java y no estoy muy familliarizado con el lenguaje, estoy revisando el codigo de un WebService y hay algunas cosas que no logro comprender, busque informacion sobre estas dos clases y la poca que encontre fue en ingles pero no pude comprenderla completamente el uso de estas dos clases. Este es el codigo donde estan instanciadas estas dos clases en mi Web Service

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ASN.class);
                    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
```

Lo que logre comprender es que JAXBContext es una clase que instanciandola sirve para manejar XML.
ASN es la clase que contiene el XML y se validará
y mas abajo se instancia Unmarshaller y se utiliza el metodo createUnmarshaller de jc. No entiendo exactamente si estoy en lo correcto con lo poco que logro entender ni tampoco para que sirve

Answer (score 0):

Con JAXB puedes convertir una clase Java a un formato XML y viceversa.

Este ejemplo puede aclararte el uso de JAXB.

1. Creamos una clase.

   package modelo;

   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

   @XmlRootElement
   public class Datos{

   ```
   private double valor;  

   public double getValor() {
       return valor;
   }

   @XmlElement
   public void setValor(double valor) {
       this.valor = valor;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Convertimos esa clase a un formato XML.

   package control;

   import java.io.File;
   import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
   import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
   import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
   import modelo.Datos;
   import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

   public class ControlDatosXml {

   public static void main(String[] args){
            Datos datos= new Datos();
            double valor = 33.11;
            datos.setValor(valor);

   ```
        try {
               File file = new File("/home/fernando/PruebasClases/datos.xml");
               JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Datos.class);
               Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
               jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
               jaxbMarshaller.marshal(datos, file);
               jaxbMarshaller.marshal(datos, System.out);
             } catch (JAXBException e) {
               System.err.println("Ha ocurrido una excepcion: "+e.toString());
             }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hecho!!");

   }
   ```

   }
3. Convertimos ese formato XML a un objeto Java.

   package control;

   import java.io.File;
   import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
   import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
   import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
   import modelo.Datos;

   public class ControlDatosClass {

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args){
       try {
               File file = new File("/home/fernando/PruebasClases/datos.xml");
               JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Datos.class);
               Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
               Datos datos = (Datos) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
               System.out.println(datos);
               System.out.println("Valor: "+datos.getValor());
         } catch (JAXBException e) {
              System.err.println("Ha ocurrido una excepcion: "+e.toString());
         }

   }
   ```

   }

Espero esto te sirva.